# Where are the Safari bookmarks stored on a computer

Tags: macos, safari, catalina, bookmarks

I just purchased a new iMac. I want to know how to transfer my old bookmarks from my old iMac running High Sierra to my new iMac running Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer the entire account with Migration Assistant, which should include all settings including bookmarks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just wanting to transfer your **Safari** *Bookmarks*, then:

In **Safari**, on your old **Mac**, you can export the *bookmarks*, **Safari** > **File** > **Export Bookmarks…** and you can then import them on your new **Mac** using, **Safari** > **File** > **Import Bookmarks…**.

**Note:** In **macOS High Sierra** the **Safari** *bookmarks* are stored in **~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist**. You can copy the *file* to the same location, with **Safari** closed, on your new **Mac** if you do not have any *bookmarks* yet.